# File permission 755 is not set while uploading file on cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have tried many times when I upload my project files on cPanel using zip file with selection 755 permission it set 755 permission only on zip file but not set 755 permission inside zip folder sub files.

I have lot of files and I can't give manually 755 permission because it's lot of files and without 755 permission my projects gives error with `404 Not Found`.

I am using this way at the time of file uploading show in below image, so how to give file permission that are located inside zip folder?

[image]

Comment: Set your folder properties to 777

Answer (score 0):

zip does not store file permissions in the archive, I think you will have to try this with .tar file instead of .zip.